# Why is the display of labels and data not aligned using twitter bootstrap 2 if the content of a <dd> element is blank?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, html, layout, twitter-bootstrap

I am seeing unexpected behavior with the description list `<dl>` tag.

I am using twitter bootstrap 2 and with this example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
  <dt>Item1</strong></dt><dd>This is a description of Item1</dd>
  <dt>Item2</strong></dt><dd>This is a description of Item2</dd>
  <dt>Item3</strong></dt><dd>This is a description of Item3</dd>
  <dt>Item4</strong></dt><dd>This is a description of Item4</dd>
  <dt>Item5</strong></dt><dd>This is a description of Item5</dd>
</dl>
```

... all works as expected and I see this:

```
Item1 This is a description of Item1  
Item2 This is a description of Item2  
Item3 This is a description of Item3  
Item4 This is a description of Item4  
Item5 This is a description of Item5
```

With this code though:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
  <dt>Item1</strong></dt><dd>This is a description of Item1</dd>
  <dt>Item2</strong></dt><dd></dd>
  <dt>Item3</strong></dt><dd>This is a description of Item3</dd>
  <dt>Item4</strong></dt><dd>This is a description of Item4</dd>
  <dt>Item5</strong></dt><dd>This is a description of Item5</dd>
</dl>
```

I see this problematic display:

```
Item1 This is a description of Item1
Item2 This is a description of Item3
Item3 This is a description of Item4
Item4 This is a description of Item5 
Item5
```

And the `<dt>` and `<dd>` tags do not match-up as expected.

Reading the w3.org working draft here http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/dl.html#dl

... it's not clear to me if the browser or the programmer are responsible for matching up the `<dt>` and `<dd>` elements when the content for `<dd>` is blank.

I tested the above code in firefox and Safari and see the same output.

Is this a matter of opinion, a bug in twitter bootstrap 2, or am I misunderstanding the use of the HTML5 description list?  This use of `<dl>` appears in show.html.erb code auto generated by

`rake g bootstrap:themed model`

If a data element is blank, the displayed output does not match the label.  It's unfortunate, because the themed option is pretty useful otherwise.

I can partially 'fix the problem' by modifying the themed output to look like this:

```
<dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:name) %>:</strong></dt>
<dd><%= @server.name %> <%= "-blank-" if @server.name.blank? %> </dd>
```

... but I am left seeing "-blank-" to display the blank elements.  If I use something like a string containing a space, like " ", I still see the same label-description misalignment problem.

Please try to focus your answer on describing which entity, the HTML5 `<dl>` tag, bootstrap, or my understanding, is off target here and why.

Thanks very much!

-EDIT-
For those working with bootstrap, using css like this works fine:

```
dt, dd {
  line-height: 20px;
  /* Keep this the same as line-height */
  min-height: 20px;
 }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default `<dt>` and `<dd>` are block-level elements, there is no need "align" them in any way, they naturally displayed one after another.

Bootstrap's `.dl-horizontal`, however, lines up this elements side-by-side. And when one of `<dd>` has no content, it's collapsed and others are shifted up. (Which obviously what you don't want.) This behaviour could be "fixed" like this:

```
dd {
  /* should be the same as line-height */
  min-height: 20px;
}
```

But I would not referenced this as a bug in Bootstrap. Why do you want to have a definition term with no definition? Do not displaying the term at all makes much more sense to me.

Comment: Thanks Pavlo.  I will try the css fix.  I agree that it just makes sense that a definition term should have a definition.  The issue seems to arise when <dl> is used to display record elements and their values in a database driven environment. It can be useful to see that some elements of a record have been left blank.  Perhaps an "undefined" definition of sorts?

Answer (score 4):

Another solution could be this one:

```
.dl-horizontal > dd:after {
  display: table;
  content: "";
  clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Overwriting the width and set min-height of dt and dd will solve the problem for empty or to long content both for dt and dd.

```
.dl-horizontal > dt {
  width: 51% !important;
}

.dl-horizontal > dd {
  width: 49% !important;
}

dt, dd {
  line-height: 20px;
  min-height: 20px; /* must be line-height, to allocate height for empty elements */
}
```